# Cells not aligning in embedded table

Tags: html, html-table, html-email, inline

I'm trying to create an embedded table with three tables for an email. The reason why I'm using tables is because I want the tables to stack one on top of another when the email renders on a smaller screen. Not all email clients read CSS well, so I'm looking for inline HTML coding, not a CSS solution.

The content table in total is 600px wide. And within that, Table 1 is 299px wide, table 2 is 2px wide, and table 3 is 299 px wide.

The first challenge I had was the row height on table 2 wasn't 100% with tables 1 and 3. I fixed that by changing the row height to 100% on the content table and in table 2. That seems to fix the row height for table 2, but then table three gets pushed down.

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/robertschlotzhauer/snk6pjb9/

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" height="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="299">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;line-height:18px">
                                <div align="center">
                                    <font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px;">
                                        <b>
                                            Text
                                        </b>
                                     </font>


                                 </td>
                             </tr>
                         </tbody>

                     </table>
                     <table bgcolor="#8C231C" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%">
                         <tbody>
                             <tr>
                                 <td style="line-height:2px" bgcolor="#8C231C" width="2px">
                                     <font style="font-size:2px">

                                         &nbsp;                  


                                      </font>

                                  </td>
                              </tr>
                          </tbody>
                      </table>
                  <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="299" valign="top" align="right">
                      <tbody>
                          <tr>
                              <td style="padding:10px 20px 0px 20px;line-height:18px">
                                  <div align="center">
                                      <font style="font-size:16px;" face="arial">
                                          <b>
                                              Text text text
                                          </b>
                                       </font>
                                       <br>
                                       <br>
                                       <font style="font-size:12px;" face="arial">
                                           Text text text
                                       </font>
                                   </div>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               </td>
           </tr>
       </tbody>
   </table>
```

Any recommendations on cleaning this up would be helpful.

Comment: Why are you using tables and not `<div>`'s for this? This coding standard was aged out in the late 90s.

Comment: Using tables so they each align under one another when viewing it on a smaller screen within an email client. On the desktop they should align in a straight row, but on a client table 1 should be on top and table three on the bottom.

Comment: Please edit your question to make this clear, as it says nothing about that. Also your jsfiddle contains completely different html to what you posted in your question.

Comment: The question has been edited to make the situation a bit clearer.

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to achieve/what's the issue you're havng? are you trying to make  it making it responsive to stack on top of each other? Are you trying to do something with that 2px table? Just want to clarify before I think about cleaning it up

Comment: Thanks lejimmie. - ultimately i want to make the tables responsive so they stack on top of each other on smaller screens. The issues lies I think with the second table - the 2px one. That is supposed to serve as a separator between tables. On a desktop - that will serve as a red line going between the two and on a mobile screen, table 1 will be on top, the 2px table will run between tables 1 and 3. The first thing I've encountered is that when I align them, the 2px table doesn't span the row height 100% - it only does so for 2px.

Comment: And when I set the row height for 100%, table three falls below the cell - which is what the JSFiddle is showing now. What I'm trying to make happen is that all tables align across a row with the 2px table stretching the entire height of the row.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do CSS. There is no raw html way to really do it. You can do mostly through inline, but there will be some backup media query necessary.  see below code snippet:

```css
.contenttable {width:600px;}
.big {width:299px;}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
 table {width:100% !important; max-width:none !important;}
 td {border-collapse:collapse !important; padding-left:0 !important; padding-right:0 !important;}
}
```

```html
<body>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
  <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="299" align="left">
<![endif]-->
<table class="contenttable" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:600px;">
  <tbody>
        <tr>
      <td style="font-size:1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:5px" bgcolor="#8C231C" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="center">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
  <tbody>
  
    <tr height="100%">
      <td>
        
        <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:299px;" class="big">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:16px; padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:15px; padding-right:10px; padding-top:15px; line-height:18px"><b>In This Issue</b></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td align="center">
              <table align="center" width="299" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="width:299px !important;">
              <tr>
              <td align="left" style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px">
              <ol>
                  <li>
                    <font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">
                      Text text text
                    </font>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">
                      Text text text
                    </font>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">
                      Text text text
                    </font>
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    <font style="font-family:Arial;font-size:12px;">
                      Text text text
                    </font>
                  </li>
                </ol>
              </td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      </td><td align="right" width="299">
<![endif]-->      
         <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width:299px;" class="big">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:10px; padding-top:20px; font-size:16px; font-family:Arial; line-height:18px"><b>Text text text</b></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:20px; font-size:12px; font-family:Arial; line-height:15px">Text text text</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
              <td align="center" style="padding-left:10px; padding-bottom:10px;"><img style="width:150px;height:50px;" src="http://img.en25.com/EloquaImages/clients/LaurelSpringsSchool/{b3492627-ee05-4126-9344-9e00be069cd3}_P7-1314_RegisterNowRed__Button.jpg"></div>
              </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
      

      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-size:1px; mso-line-height-rule:exactly; line-height:5px" bgcolor="#8C231C" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<![endif]-->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Goronington! The 2x separator table doesn't seem to be rendering :(